# python delay a program for n seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x

is there a function in python that delays a program from running for n number of seconds?
I am trying to achieve something like this:

```py
print("Hello")
delay(5) #delays the program by 5 seconds
print("World!")
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated, Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure!

```
import time

print("Hello")
time.sleep(5) #delays the program by 5 seconds
print("World!")
```